# str relace method confusion

Tags: python, string, replace

```
x=["a = 1;","b = input();","if a + b > 0 && a - b < 0:"]
for i in range(len(x)):
    y = x[i]
    y.replace(" && ", " and ")
    y.replace(" || ", " or ")
    print(y)
```

This code is suppose to print

```
a = 1; 
b = input(); 
if a + b > 0 and a - b < 0:
```

but I am getting result which corresponds to replace method not working. I have tried this on colab as well as jupiter notebook.

```
a = 1; 
b = input();
if a + b > 0 && a - b < 0:
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of `replace()` to a variable. Strings are immutable, so it can't modify in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Python cannot be modified.  The `replace` function returns a new string with the change.

```
y = y.replace(" && ", " and ")
y = y.replace(" || ", " or ")
```

Which can, of course, be combined into one statement.